# Adding new elements using asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net

for example, i have text box and i have entered "**for example**".

now, i want to create a new `<table>` and a `<tr>` to that table, and a `<td>` for each ward entered.

how can i do that?Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//figure out the number of table row and column.
  int rowNum =  5;
  int colNum = 2;
  System.Text.StringBuilder sb=new System.Text.StringBuilder();
  if(attachmentName.Count > 0){
        sb.Append("<Table>");
        for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
                sb.Append("<tr>");
                for (int j = 0; j < colNum; j++)
                {
                    sb.Append("<td>");
                    //add your a tab and img tag....
                    // by attachmentName[i][j]
                    sb.Append("");
                    sb.Append("</td>");
                }
                sb.Append("</tr>");
            }
      }
```

Source: http://forums.asp.net/t/1955897.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should use [HTMLGeneric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class for that.

Suppose that you want to add a `tr` you can create it as follows

```
HtmlGenericControl tr = new HtmlGenericControl("tr");
```

You can add td in tr as follows

```
HtmlGenericControl td = new HtmlGenericControl("td");
tr.Controls.Add(td);
```

Similarly you can create any html controls

and finally add it in your parent control which is on the page. Suppose it is a panel with id pannel1 then

```
 pannel1.Controls.Add(panle1);
```